# How can I choose where a sprite enters a 2D game?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently building a 2D platformer game for my CS class in pygame, and I need help with the code I would use to choose where my player sprite enters the game, as displayed on my "level" layout. I want an "I" block in the bottom left to be where my player enters the level. Any idea how I could go about this?

```
for row in level:
    for block in row:
        if block == "P":
            p = platform(x, y)
            platforms.append(p)
            all_sprites.add(p)
```

this is what I have now for my platforms, and I would like it to stay in a similar format if possible.

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least give us more info. We have no idea of what is `platform` and what are these "I" or "P" blocks, so it's difficult to provide ad adequate answer. The only thing I can suggest is to add another if in your inner loop: `elif block == "I":` to add the "I" block.

Comment: it seems you want to keep char `I` and `P` in the same place in `level`. Maybe you should use different letter (ie. lower `p` ) which will means `I+P`

Comment: My apologies, it was just too big to put into the code block and have it look the same. It is essentially a variable with strings outlining what I want the level to look like using letters like 'W' for walls, 'F' for floors, 'E' for an end block, and 'P' for platforms. I wanted the letter 'I' to become the spawn point for my character. I hope that helps some, it's tough for me to explain fully.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple addition to your code.

Simply add the case for detecting an I and then making a sprite.

```
for row in level:
    for block in row:
        if block == "P":
            p = platform(x, y)
            platforms.append(p)
            all_sprites.add(p)

        elif block == "I": # Find player character
            player = player(x * block, y * row) # If you want it to generate based on grid location, remove if otherwise.
            all_sprites.add(p)
```